# Why does this of sfinae not work?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, compile-time-constant

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    using key_type = int;
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_key_type : false_type
{};

template<typename T>
struct has_key_type<T, decltype(typeid(typename T::key_type), void())>: true_type
{};

int main()
{
    cout << has_key_type<A>::value << endl;
    cout << has_key_type<int>::value << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
1
0
```

Which is as expected. However, if I change from

`decltype(typeid(typename T::key_type), void())`

to

`decltype(typeid(typename T::key_type), int())`

as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_key_type<T, decltype(typeid(typename T::key_type), int())>: true_type
{};
```

The output is:

```
0
0
```

**Why does the second version not work?**

Comment: Unrelated, why use typeid ? This is only for runtime check.

Comment: Use `int main`, which [is standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c).

Comment: @liliscent if I am not wrong typeid only is a runtime check with polymorphic types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not give the second template argument, so it will use the default template argument, which is `void`. In your second version, the type of `decltype(typeid(typename T::key_type), int())` is `int`, so `has_key_type<A>`, which is equivalently `has_key_type<A, void>`, will certainly not match this partial specialization.

BTW, since C++17, you can use `std::void_t` to simplify `decltype(typeid(typename T::key_type), void())` to `std::void_t<typename T::key_type>`.